# MongoDB: dictionary.get() convert as new dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I extracted documents from a MongoDB Collection.
(The documents are highly nested.)

I wanted to get a "sub-tree" with all it's nested elements. But the new sub-tree has type 'list'. How can I convert the **dictionary.get()** result to a new dictionary?

Part of the dictionary...

```
"Brand": [
    {
      "Ford": [
        {
          "Modell": "Kuga",
          "ps": "125",
          "registered": true
        },
        {
          "Modell": "Focus",
          "ps": "78",
          "registered": false
        }
```

(etc).

After executing  `dictionary.get("Brand", "")`  I got the expeced sub-tree. But it's stored as "list".

```
{
   'Ford':[
      {
         'Modell':'Kuga',
         'ps':'125',
         'registered':True
      },
      {
         'Modell':'Focus',
         'ps':'78',
         'registered':False
      }
   ],
   'VW':[
      {
         'Modell':'Polo',
         'ps':'88',
         'registered':True
      }
```

(etc).

To get a "sub-tree" with it's nested elements, I used the `dictionary.get()` Method.

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://someCollections')
mydb = myclient['data']
mycol = mydb['Test_CarList'] 

x = mycol.find_one()  # type 'dictionary'
jsonOut = x.get("Brand", "")  # jsonOut = type 'list'
```

Actual:

```
jsonOut = x.get("Brand", "")  # jsonOut = type 'list'
```

Expected:

```
jsonOut = x.get("Brand", "")  # jsonOut = type 'dictionary'
```

Comment: As you can see in your original data, `Brand` is a key that contains a *list*. You're asking to get the value of the `Brand` key, which results in returning you... a *list*. What you're asking per-se is not possible without more specific details.

Comment: SOLVED: @IMCoins : Thanks!  As "Brand" just contains one entry, `dictionary.get("Brand", "")[0] ` solved the problem. The issue was, that I created the dictionary myself and added a list with one element with muliple objects, instead of adding the objects directly!